# Cookies secure in browser?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies

I'm making a website that uses javascript to decrypt information when it reaches the client. I was planning to have them enter their password once and then it would be stored in a cookie (which is not sent over the internet, stays on clients browser), then the javascript uses the cookie to decrypt the info when it reaches the client. Is the password cookie secure as long as it never goes over the internet. If not what are my options?

Comment: Uhm, you might want to learn how cookies work. They are *always* sent to the server, over the internet.

Comment: `which is not sent over the internet` - yes it is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: Not really sure how the system is supposed to work, but in general it's almost always a bad idea to make your own security implementation. What's wrong with getting an SSL certificate and not having to worry about connection encryption at all?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is always going to be sent to server (over the internet). If you want to keep the data at client side, you can use localstorage in browsers.